# How to customize silly "Hello from Twilio!" SMS reply? (sent out when recipient doesn't use known keyword)

Tags: twilio, reply, unsubscribe

I'm sending out SMS in an application. Some portion of the users use the well known unsubscribe keywords like STOP, stop and alike. Some people reply back like there was human on the other end. Like "Why am I getting this message".

Here comes the interesting thing: in such case Twilio replies with a silly "Hello from Twilio!" SMS, which confuses the recipient even more (the recipient is involved with a service with company X and doesn't know at all that we use Twilio for SMS delivery).

Where can I change that message? I'm using the Twilio API to send SMS from our back-end, I don't have any messaging service configured (and I don't even want to have any unless I have to) just as I don't want any "Advanced Opt-Out for Messaging Services" because I don't want to override or customize any unsubscribe keywords or anything. I just want to have a more meaningful reply SMS than the silly "Hello from Twilio!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In your phone number configuration, which you can find by navigating to your [list of phone numbers](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming) then clicking on the phone number, you can scroll down to find the messaging section. It looks a bit like this:

[image]

You may have a demo URL set in the field for what happens when "A message comes in". That demo URL is likely returning the "Hello from Twilio!" response to incoming messages.

To override this, you can either remove the URL entirely, or set it to your own response. You can use this to alert your users that the number is not monitored, or just not respond. To do this, I'd recommend using a [TwiML Bin](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/tutorials/twiml-bins) as they let you host static TwiML that can react like this.

If you want to use a TwiML Bin to stop the number responding at all, set up a TwiML Bin with this TwiML:

```xml
<Response/>
```

If you'd like to send a message of your own in response, use this TwiML:

```xml
<Response>
  <Message>Thanks for messaging, but messages to this number are not monitored. If you want to opt out of messages, send STOP.</Message>
</Response>
```

Fill in your own message, of course.

Comment: Wow, I'll try this tomorrow. I tried to find relevant things with various search keywords but haven't found this information.

Comment: I cannot find that messaging section you screenshotted.

Comment: I don't have any Messaging Services configured.

Comment: At the phone number line I had a link to Start a TwiML service. I clicked on it and I could edit a Response, which is now working instead of the demo reply. However I still don't have any services listed under the services after that. My problem is solved though.

Comment: While I am glad that your problem is solved, I am not sure I understand your comments. Did you find the section I screenshotted? You should be able to find it by navigating to your [list of phone numbers](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming) then clicking on the phone number you are talking about. This is not about messaging services in this case and you don't need a messaging service for this behaviour.

Comment: Ok, I see the screenshotted section now. Can you add this to the top of your answer? "You should be able to find it by navigating to your list of phone numbers then clicking on the phone number" and scrolling down to messaging. Now I see there the TwiML what I configured.

Comment: Updated . Glad you are now sorted with all of this.